RNFS library can't track progress or the bytewritten doesn't make sense
What am I doing wrong I have divided the bytesWritten by the filesize and multiplied by 100 but the persentage never makes sense and when check the byteWritten against the actual file size in the disk it's not the same. below is my code:
const fileExists = await RNFS.exists(path);
if (fileExists) {
    return path;
} else {
    setIsDownloading(true);
    setDownloadProgress(0);
    console.log('Downloading file: ' + file_url + ' path: ' + path);
    const downloadOptions = {
        fromUrl: file_url,
        toFile: path,
        background: true,
        discretionary: true,
        cacheable: true,
        begin: (res) => {
            console.log('Response begin ===\n\n');
            console.log(res);
        },
        progress: (res) => {
            // console.log('Response progress ===\n\n', res);
            const progress = (res.bytesWritten / res.contentLength) * 100;
            // console.log(
            //   `Bytes Written: ${res.bytesWritten}, Content Length: ${res.contentLength}, Progress: ${progress}%`,
            // );
            setDownloadProgress(progress);
        },
    };
    // Download the file
    const result = await RNFS.downloadFile(downloadOptions).promise.then(
        res => {
            return res;
        },
    );
}

I tried the code up but the result doesn't make sense, actually it's totally different

How does the percentage not make sense?  What value is it printing, and why do you think it's wrong?  What are the values for bytesWritten and contentLength?

LOG  Bytes Written: 337254692, Content Length: 895082496, Progress: 376.79%

Since the right answer is 37.6%, it looks like you're multiplying by 100 again somewhere.  Most likely your setDownloadProgress expects a value between 0 and 1, rather than a percent

Yes I have solved it somehow by changing the progress to
const progress = ((100 * res.bytesWritten) / res.contentLength) | 0;
Thanks
